# Simple_form_for - show validation errors for each field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple forms which is working well in a sense that it shows the validation error:

```
<%= simple_form_for( @my_model, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "input-xlarge" } }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => t("title") %>
    </p>
    ......
```

but it just isn't showing which of the fields are invalid. How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it this way:

```
<%= simple_form_for( @my_model, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "input-xlarge" } }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <p>
      <%= f.input :title, :placeholder => t("title") %>
    </p>
    ......
```

use `input` instead of `text_field`.

Check examples in documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage).

Hope that helps!

```
<%= simple_form_for( @my_model, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "input-xlarge" } }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs <% unless @my_model.errors[:title].empty? %>error<% end %>">
    <p>
      <%= f.input_field title, :placeholder => t("title") %>
      <%= f.full_error :title %>
    </p>
    ......
```

Comment: it completely changes what my inputs look like now, that's not good, another way?

Comment: Well, this is how simple_form works. I'm afraid there is no other way... Do you use any frontend library? Bootstrap, or?

Comment: Hey @jawanam, just updated the answer - take a look how you can try to customise your form!

Comment: Thanks, but I need not only title, but all the fields.

Comment: @jawanam - with provided syntax you have to list all your fields, like with plain Rails `form_for`